# Вечный цикл

Tags: php, циклы

Как сделать, чтобы код выполнялся постоянно и сервер не остановил из-за лимита времени на выполнение?

Это нужно для функционирования бота в "игре". Бота видят все игроки, его перемещение и действия также видят все без задержек. То есть он должен выполняться на стороне сервера, и выполняться постоянно. К созданию бота приступил только что, и сразу задумался над такой проблемой...

В середине "вечного цикла" хотел использовать `sleep()` для задержки перед действиями.

Как Вам такая реализация? Это первое, что пришло в голову, и лучше ничего не придумал. Если есть идеи или опыт в подобных вещах, с радостью выслушаю.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Два варианта:

1. постоянно работающий скрипт - его запускаете не через браузер, а на сервере, как `daemon` («демон»), он висит себе в памяти и постоянно что-то там делает. [Например](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/).
2. если игра более-ли-менее пошаговая, то можно и по крону, раз в 1 или в 5 минут запускать нужный php скрипт, опять же, не через веб, а командную строку (CLI).

Comment: первое больше подходит, и за пример спасибо. буду пробовать

Comment: Либо попробуйте скрипт запустить через cron.php, хотя могу ошибаться!

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так:
Скрипт контролирует свое время исполнения, и когда оно становится больше 20, то он сохраняет результат работы, [асинхронно](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-socket-client.php) вызывает сам себя и делает die.
В отличие от запуска по крону этот способ гарантирует постоянную работу и невозможность одновременной работы двух копий.
В отличие от демона этот способ будет работать на хостинге, который не дает демонов.

Answer (score 1):

[Замечательная функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php) устанавливает предел времени выполнения, если передать нуль, то предела нет

Comment: это если хостинг провайдер не обрежет.